# Test case search page component field showing duplicates

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Kiwi tcms portal has page for searching test cases with set of fields like product, category and components.

Product and category listing are proper in dropdown.
But component field showing duplicates in dropdown. Duplicated count based on test cases count which are associated with that component.

Is this known issue ? Can we resolve from our side using any customization in hosted files or DB ? Or need to resolve by concern vendor.

Note: While viewing component in component listing page it is proper. only search test case page has this duplication issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. It may be helpful to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).